# Norm in terms of an infimum obtained from a subset of a normed vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> Take a convex and bounded subset $A$ of a normed vector space $V$ so that the closed ball (defined with the norm of V) $B[0, r] \subset A$ for some $r>0$.
>
> We have as well that if $v \in A$, then $-v \in A .$
>
> We want to show that the map $N: V \rightarrow [0, 1)$, $
> N(v) = \inf_k \left\{k>0: v/k \in A\right\}$ is another norm on $V$.

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that the vector space is on $\mathbb{C}$.

-

I have shown that $N(v)=0$ iff $v=0$. But I don't know how to make progress in proving the two remaining conditions. Namely  $N(av)=|a|N(v)$ and $N(v+u) \le N(v)+N(u)$.

I have tried to derive these from the definition of $N$ and infimum, but I'm not making any progress. Thanks for any help.

Comment: See [Minkowski functional](https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/func-an-2007-2008/conv-w-2.pdf).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Thanks, I didn't know it had a name. I thought it was just a contrived construction.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net After reading this, the problem is that your link uses very different hypotheses. I'm sure they can be proved to be equivalent to the hypothesis in my question, but doing this seems to be as hard as proving the problem in my question which unfortunately doesn't help much.