# Minkowski functional: proving $N(av)=|a|N(v)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

This question is related to this one [Norm in terms of an infimum obtained from a subset of a normed vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565745/norm-in-terms-of-an-infimum-obtained-from-a-subset-of-a-normed-vector-space?noredirect=1#comment7331871_3565745).

It says:

> Take a convex and bounded subset $A$ of a normed vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$, so that the closed ball (defined with the norm of V) $B[0, r] \subset A$ for some $r>0$.
>
> We have as well that if $v \in A$, then $-v \in A .$
>
> We want to show that the map $N: V \rightarrow [0, 1)$, $
> N(v) = \inf_k \left\{k>0: v/k \in A\right\}$ is another norm on $V$.

I have shown that (i) $N(v)=0$ iff $v=0$, and that (ii) $N(v+u) \le N(v)+N(u)$, but I'm having troubles showing that (iii) $N(av)=|a|N(v)$ with the given hypothesis.

I have already used convexness, boundedness and the closed ball to get (i) and (ii). But I don't see how to get (iii) with those assumptions and the symmetric property of $A$.

Comment: Could you prove it over $\Bbb R$? Over $\Bbb C$ we might need $v\in A\implies \lambda v\in A$ for all $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Norm in terms of an infimum obtained from a subset of a normed vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565745/norm-in-terms-of-an-infimum-obtained-from-a-subset-of-a-normed-vector-space)

Comment: @Berci Unfortunately, no.  So, you suggest trying proving for R, and then extending to C, somehow?

Comment: @DavideMorgante no this is the one referred to in my question.  The file there uses different assumptions, so it not very helpful for this specific problem.

Comment: You need $\alpha A \subset A$ for all $|\alpha| \le 1$. $-A$ is sufficient for a real space but not for a complex one.

Comment: @copper.hat I think I get it for real space, thanks.